# script not getting proper image height at initial call, but succesfull all other calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Alright so I have a bit of jquery code that gets called from:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#AdsLarge').adRotator({
                num_li: 2,
                pauseTime: 5000,
                pauseDom: $('#AdsButtons li span#Ads_Pause'),
                resumeDom: $('#AdsButtons li span#Ads_Resume'),
                upDom: $('#AdsButtons li span#Ads_Up'),
                downDom: $('#AdsButtons li span#Ads_Down')
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Script:

```
       $.fn.extend({
            adRotator: function(option){
                var defaults = {
                    pauseTime: 5000,
                    num_li: null,
                    pauseDom: null,
                    resumeDom: null,
                    upDom: null,
                    downDom: null
                }
                var options = $.extend(defaults, option);

                return this.each(function () {

                    //get ul
                    var txtSlider = $(this),
                        //get li's
                        adSlides = txtSlider.children(),
                        //top li
                        topSlide = adSlides.first(),
                        //last li
                        lastSlide = adSlides.last(),
                        //get height of div and make it a negative to make it slide UP
                        newHeight = -Math.abs(topSlide.height());



                    var adRotatorInterval = null;
                    //set the interval
                    adRotatorInterval = setInterval(slideUp, options.pauseTime);
                    //slide the Li up or down
                    function slideUp() {
                        clearInterval(adRotatorInterval);
                        adRotatorInterval = null;
                        newHeight = -Math.abs(topSlide.height());
                        topSlide.animate({ marginTop: newHeight }, 500, 'easeInOutQuad', function () {
                            topSlide.detach();
                            topSlide.insertAfter(lastSlide);
                            topSlide.css({ marginTop: 10 });
                            adSlides = txtSlider.children();
                            topSlide = adSlides.first();
                            lastSlide = adSlides.last();
                            FixSize();
                        });
                        adRotatorInterval = setInterval(slideUp, options.pauseTime);
                    }
                    function slideDown() {
                        clearInterval(adRotatorInterval);
                        adRotatorInterval = null;
                        newHeight = -Math.abs(topSlide.height());
                        lastSlide.detach();
                        lastSlide.insertBefore(topSlide);
                        lastSlide.css({ marginTop: newHeight });
                        lastSlide.animate({ marginTop: 10 }, 500, 'easeInOutQuad', function () {
                            adSlides = txtSlider.children();
                            topSlide = adSlides.first();
                            lastSlide = adSlides.last();
                            FixSize();
                        });
                        adRotatorInterval = setInterval(slideUp, options.pauseTime);
                    }

                    //check to see if a pause/resume.up/down dom elements were selected to be used
                    //if so tie in an click function
                    if (options.pauseDom) {
                        $(options.pauseDom).click(function () {
                            if (adRotatorInterval) {
                                clearInterval(adRotatorInterval);
                                adRotatorInterval = null;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    if (options.resumeDom) {
                        $(options.resumeDom).click(function () {
                            if (!adRotatorInterval) {
                                slideUp();
                                adRotatorInterval = setInterval(slideUp, options.pauseTime);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    if (options.upDom) {
                        $(options.upDom).click(function () {
                            slideUp();
                        });
                    }
                    if (options.downDom) {
                        $(options.downDom).click(function () {
                            slideDown();
                        });
                    }

                    function FixSize() {
                        if (options.num_li) {
                            var num_slides_height = options.num_li;
                        } else {
                            var num_slides_height = adSlides.length();
                        }

                        var total_Height = 0;
                        var theSlide = topSlide;
                        var css_prop = { height: 'height', mtop: 'margin-top', mbottom: 'margin-bottom', ptop: 'padding-top', pbottom: 'padding-bottom' };
                        while (num_slides_height > 0) {
                            $.each(css_prop, function (index, value) {
                                if (parseInt(theSlide.css(value).replace('px', '')) > 0) {
                                    total_Height += parseInt(theSlide.css(value).replace('px', ''))
                                } else {
                                    total_Height += 0;
                                };
                            });
                            theSlide = theSlide.next();
                            num_slides_height--;
                        }
                        total_Height += 10;
                        txtSlider.css({ height: total_Height });
                    }


                    //set the fixsize function to the resize event
                    $(window).on('resize', function () {
                        FixSize();
                    });

                    //run FixSize for the first time
                    FixSize();
                }); 
            }
        });
```

My problem here is that when FixSize() is initially run, i noticed (using breakpoints/locals) that the li width was what it was supposed to be but the li height is for some reason a really small number usually 21, when its actually suppose to be 298.

Every time the function is called after this the li height is 298 and eveything is just fine.

The li contains an image so i though it might be that the image wasnt loaded yet but i was wrong about that since I had already set the extension to be run at $(document).ready

I have a feeling that this issue has something to do with the time at which the function is being called but I cant put my hand on it.

My question is: How do i fix this issue so that the height is set propperly before the client see's it?
Any help would be appreciative.

Comment: Most likely this happens because the browser is not done loading the image yet, so it doesn’t know its dimensions at this point. Go research how to handle an image’s `load` event for how to fix this.

Comment: Its my understanding that $(document).ready is saying that everything has been loaded and the document is ready to be viewed. Wouldent that mean the image is loaded and the dimensions set, also seeing how the width is set why wouldent the height be set.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. http://api.jquery.com/ready/: _“Specify a function to execute when **the DOM** is fully loaded.”_

Comment: So im not disagreeing with either of you, as I already said i think it has to do with the image not being loaded but, I cant understand from the link you just posted " this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received",  adding a .load to the dom element doesnt resolve the situation.

Comment: Have you tried executing on `$(window).load( ... )` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried but it still happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is becuase the image is not done loading yet!